# Show text momentarily in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

i am trying to make an application similar to Clock in iOS.
I am trying to display a text when the alarm clock slots are full, or when no more alarms could be added (limit is four). I have no idea how to do that. I have tried with the showText function but that does not work and I don't know why

```
from picCLS import *
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
import time
import pygame,sys
t0 = time.time()
months = ['January', 'Febuary', 'March', 'April', 'May',
          'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October',
          'November', 'December']
dateC = ['st', 'nd', 'rd'] + ['th'] * 28
alList = ['None'] * 4

class CLS_photoship(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.scr = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Clockhood')
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.font = pygame.font.Font('IEB.ttf', 50)
        self.font2 = pygame.font.Font('IEB.ttf', 15)
        self.font3 = pygame.font.Font('IEB.ttf', 60)
        self.spd = 5
        self.effNum = 0
        self.mousePos = (0,0)
        self.guideList = []
        self.guideId = 0
        self.h = 0
        self.m = 0
        self.s = 0
        self.hA = 0
        self.mA = 0
        self.running = 0
        self.TIME = ''
        self.al = ''
        self.flagAl = 0
        self.lastAl = ''
        self.FULL = False
    def play(self):
        if self.running == 0:
            self.h, self.m, self.s = 0, 0, 0
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(self.h, self.m, self.s)
        sw = '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(self.h, self.m, self.s)
        al = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(self.hA, self.mA)
        self.al = al
        today = date.today()
        DATE = str(today)
        dateL = DATE.split('-')
        t = time.localtime()
        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        CUR = str(current_time)
        dateM = dateL[2] + dateC[int(dateL[2]) - 1]
        for guide in self.guideList:
            guide.draw(self.scr)
        #___get text x___
        TimeX = 580 - (getTextSize(CUR))
        MonthX = 300 - (getTextSize(getMonth(dateL[1])) / 2)
        YearX = 300 - (getTextSize(dateL[0]) / 2)
        DayX = 300 - (getTextSize(dateM) / 2)
        timerX = 300 - (getTextSizeB(timer) / 2)
        swX = 300 - (getTextSizeB(sw) / 2)
        alX = 300 - (getTextSizeB(al) / 2)
        self.TIME = CUR
        #pygame.display.update()
        #___display text___
        self.h = int((time.time() - t0) // 3600)
        self.m = int((time.time() - t0 - self.h * 3600) // 60)
        self.s = int((time.time() - t0) % 60 // 1)
        if pship.guideId == G01.id:
            showText(pship.scr, CUR, pship.font, TimeX, 535, (255, 255, 255))
            showText(pship.scr, getMonth(dateL[1]) + ' ' + dateM, pship.font, 30, 535, (255, 255, 255))
        if pship.guideId == G03.id:
            showText(pship.scr, timer, pship.font3, timerX, 230, (255, 255, 255))
        if pship.guideId == G02.id:
            showText(pship.scr, sw, pship.font3, swX, 230, (255, 255, 255))
            pygame.display.update()
        if pship.guideId == G05.id:
            showText(pship.scr, al, pship.font3, alX, 260, (255, 255, 255))
            pygame.display.update()
        if CUR[0:5] in alList and self.flagAl == 0:
            pygame.mixer.init()
            pygame.mixer.music.load('ringtone2.mp3')
            pygame.mixer.music.play(loops = 1)
            self.flagAl = 1
            self.lastAl = CUR[0:5]
        if not CUR[0:5] == self.lastAl:
            self.flagAl = 0
        if pship.guideId == G04.id:
            for alarm in range(4):
                try:
                    if alarm == 0:
                        aX = 160 - (getTextSizeB(alList[alarm]) / 2)
                        aY = 190
                    if alarm == 1:
                        aX = 440 - (getTextSizeB(alList[alarm]) / 2)
                        aY = 190
                    if alarm == 2:
                        aX = 160 - (getTextSizeB(alList[alarm]) / 2)
                        aY = 420
                    if alarm == 3:
                        aX = 440 - (getTextSizeB(alList[alarm]) / 2)
                        aY = 420
                    showText(pship.scr, alList[alarm], pship.font3, aX, aY, (255, 255, 255))
                except:
                    if alarm == 0:
                        aX = 160 - (getTextSizeB('None') / 2)
                        aY = 190
                    if alarm == 1:
                        aX = 440 - (getTextSizeB('None') / 2)
                        aY = 190
                    if alarm == 2:
                        aX = 160 - (getTextSizeB('None') / 2)
                        aY = 420
                    if alarm == 3:
                        aX = 440 - (getTextSizeB('None') / 2)
                        aY = 420
                    showText(pship.scr, 'None', pship.font3, aX, aY, (255, 255, 255))
        #if self.FULL:
            #FullX = getTextSize('You reached the limit on 4 alarms')
            #showText(pship.scr, 'You reached the limit on 4 alarms', pship.font, FullX, 200, (255, 255, 255))
            #pygame.display.update()
            #time.sleep(3)
            #self.FULL = False
        pygame.display.update()
        self.clock.tick(50)
        return
    def add_guide(self, guide):
        guide.id = len(self.guideList)
        self.guideList.append(guide)
        return
    def key_up(self, key):
        return
    def key_down(self, key):
        return
    def mouse_down(self, pos, btn):
        self.guideList[self.guideId].mouse_down(pos,btn)
        return
    def mouse_up(self, pos, btn):
        self.guideList[self.guideId].mouse_up(pos, btn)
        return
    def mouse_motion(self, pos):
        self.mousePos = pos
        self.guideList[self.guideId].mouse_motion(pos)
        return
    def mouse_wheel(self, y):
        self.y = y
        if self.guideId == G03.id:
            if 360 <= self.mousePos[0] <= 445 and 240 <= self.mousePos[1] <= 295:
                self.s = (self.s + y) % 60
            elif 260 <= self.mousePos[0] <= 345 and 240 <= self.mousePos[1] <= 295:
                self.m = (self.m + y) % 60
            elif 145 <= self.mousePos[0] <= 240 and 240 <= self.mousePos[1] <= 295:
                self.h = (self.h + y) % 60
            #self.m = (self.s + y) // 60
            print(y)
            print(self.h, self.m, self.s)
        if self.guideId == G05.id:
            if 200 <= self.mousePos[0] <= 285 and 265 <= self.mousePos[1] <= 320:
                self.hA = (self.hA + y) % 24
            elif 305 <= self.mousePos[0] <= 400 and 265 <= self.mousePos[1] <= 320:
                self.mA = (self.mA + y) % 60
        return

class CLS_guide(object):
    def __init__(self, picName):
        self.pic = CLS_pic(picName)
        self.id = 0
        self.btnList = []
        self.txtList = []
        self.swList = []
    def draw(self, scr):
        if pship.guideId != self.id:
            return
        scr.blit(self.pic.img, (0, 0))
        for btn in self.btnList:
            btn.draw(scr)
        for txt in self.txtList:
            txt.draw(scr)
        return
    def add_button(self, name, picFile, x, y, guideId):
        b = CLS_button(name, picFile, x, y, guideId)
        self.btnList.append(b)
        return
    def add_txt(self, txt, font, x, y, c, rect):
        t = CLS_text(txt, font, x, y, c, rect)
        self.txtList.append(t)
        return
    def mouse_down(self, pos, button):
        for btn in self.btnList:
            btn.mouse_down(pos, button)
        return
    def mouse_up(self, pos, button):
        for btn in self.btnList:
            btn.mouse_up(pos, button)
        return
    def mouse_motion(self, pos):
        return
    
class CLS_text(object):
    def __init__(self, txt, font, x, y, c, rect):
        self.txt = txt
        self.img = font.render(txt, True, c)
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.c = c
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(rect)
    def draw(self,scr):
        if self.rect.collidepoint(pship.mousePos):
            scr.blit(self.img, (self.x, self.y))
        return

class CLS_button(object):
    def __init__(self, name, picFile, x, y, guideId):
        self.name = name
        self.img = pygame.image.load(picFile)
        self.img.set_colorkey((38, 38, 38))
        self.w, self.h = self.img.get_width(), self.img.get_height() / 2
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h)
        self.status = 0
        self.guideId = guideId
        self.run = 0
    def draw(self, scr):
        scr.blit(self.img, (self.x, self.y),
                 (0, self.run * self.rect.h, self.rect.w, self.rect.h))
        return
    def mouse_down(self, pos, button):
        return
    def mouse_up(self, pos, button):
        #self.status = (self.status + 1) % 2
        if not self.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            return
        if self.name == 'T':
            pship.guideList[self.guideId].pic.draw(pship.scr)
        elif self.name == 'SW':
            pship.guideList[self.guideId].pic.draw(pship.scr)
        elif self.name == 'A':
            pship.guideList[self.guideId].pic.draw(pship.scr)
        elif self.name == 'PoS2':
            pship.guideList[self.guideId].pic.draw(pship.scr)
            self.run = (self.run + 1) % 2
            pship.running = self.run
            #while pship.running == 1:
                #stopwatch()
            #countdown(pship.h, pship.m, pship.s)
            #print(self.run)
            
        elif self.name == 'Done2':
            pship.guideList[self.guideId].pic.draw(pship.scr)
            run = 0
            h, m, s = 0, 0, 0
            sw = '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(h, m, s)
            print(sw)
        elif self.name == 'Add':
            pship.hA = int(pship.TIME[0:2])
            pship.mA = int(pship.TIME[3:5])
        elif self.name == 'Done4':
            flaggy = 0
            for AL in range(4):
                if alList[AL] == 'None' and flaggy == 0:
                    flaggy = 1
                    empty = AL
                    break
            if flaggy == 0:
                pship.FULL = True
            alList[AL] = pship.al
            print(alList)
        elif self.name == 'M1':
            alList[0] = 'None'
        elif self.name == 'M2':
            alList[1] = 'None'
        elif self.name == 'M3':
            alList[2] = 'None'
        elif self.name == 'M4':
            alList[3] = 'None'
        pship.guideId = self.guideId
        return
   
def showText(scr, txt, font, x, y, c):
    img = font.render(txt, True, c) #True: antialiasing
    scr.blit(img,(x,y))
    return
def getTextSize(txt):
    size = pship.font.size(txt)
    return(size[0])
def getTextSizeB(txt):
    size = pship.font3.size(txt)
    return(size[0])
def getMonth(month):
    return months[int(month) - 1]


pship = CLS_photoship()
G01 = CLS_guide('Spring.png')
pship.guideId = G01.id
pship.add_guide(G01)
G02 = CLS_guide('SW.png')
pship.add_guide(G02)
G03 = CLS_guide('T.png')
pship.add_guide(G03)
G04 = CLS_guide('A.png')
pship.add_guide(G04)
G05 = CLS_guide('addP.png')
pship.add_guide(G05)
G01.add_button('A', 'BtnA.png', 150, 10, G04.id)
G01.add_button('SW', 'BtnSw.png', 10, 10, G02.id)
G01.add_button('T', 'BtnT.png', 80, 10, G03.id)
G02.add_button('Home', 'Home.png', 10, 10, G01.id)
G03.add_button('Home', 'Home.png', 10, 10, G01.id)
G04.add_button('Home', 'Home.png', 10, 10, G01.id)
G02.add_button('PoS2', 'PoS.png', 136.5, 350, G02.id)
G03.add_button('PoS3', 'PoS.png', 136.5, 350, G03.id)
G02.add_button('Done2', 'Done.png', 336.5, 350, G02.id)
G03.add_button('Done3', 'Done.png', 336.5, 350, G03.id)
G04.add_button('Add', 'addA.png', 520, 30, G05.id)
G05.add_button('Done4', 'Done.png', 236.5, 400, G04.id)
G04.add_button('M1', 'minus.png', 140, 278, G04.id)
G04.add_button('M2', 'minus.png', 420, 278, G04.id)
G04.add_button('M3', 'minus.png', 140, 508, G04.id)
G04.add_button('M4', 'minus.png', 420, 508, G04.id)
G05.add_button('Back', 'Back.png', 10, 10, G04.id)
G01.add_txt('Stopwatch', pship.font2, 5, 73, (255, 255, 255), (10, 10, 60, 60)) 
G01.add_txt('Timer', pship.font2, 91, 73, (255, 255, 255), (80, 10, 60, 60)) 
G01.add_txt('Alarm', pship.font2, 160, 73, (255, 255, 255), (150, 10, 60, 60)) 
G02.add_txt('Home', pship.font2, 20, 73, (255, 255, 255), (10, 10, 60, 60)) 
G03.add_txt('Home', pship.font2, 20, 73, (255, 255, 255), (10, 10, 60, 60)) 
G04.add_txt('Home', pship.font2, 20, 73, (255, 255, 255), (10, 10, 60, 60)) 

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            pship.key_up(event.key)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            pship.key_down(event.key)
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pship.mouse_down(event.pos, event.button)
            print(pship.mousePos)
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            pship.mouse_up(event.pos, event.button)
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            pship.mouse_motion(event.pos)
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEWHEEL:
            pship.mouse_wheel(event.y)
    pship.play()
```

The one above is the main program.
The one below is the picCLS program

```
import pygame, sys, random
SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H = 600, 600
class CLS_pic(object):
    def __init__(self, fileName):
        img = pygame.image.load(fileName)
        self.img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H))
        self.x, self.y = 0, 0
        self.w, self.h = self.img.get_size()
    def draw(self, scr):
        scr.blit(self.img, (self.x, self.y), (0, 0, self.w, self.h))
    def filter(self, scr, filterNum):
        if filterNum == 1:
            for y in range(self.h):
                for x in range(self.w):
                    r0, g0, b0, alpha = self.img.get_at((x, y))
                    gray = int(0.3 * r0 + 0.59 * g0 + 0.11 * b0)
                    c = (gray, gray, gray)
                    scr.set_at((x, y), c)
                pygame.display.update()
        elif filterNum == 2:
            img0 = pygame.transform.scale(self.img, (SCREEN_W, SCREEN_W))
            img1 = pygame.Surface((SCREEN_W, SCREEN_W))
            n = self.w
            a = int(self.w / 2)
            for y in range(a):
                for x in range(y, a):
                    img1.set_at((x, y), img0.get_at((x, y)))
                    img1.set_at((y, x), img0.get_at((x, y)))
                    img1.set_at((n - 1 - x, y), img0.get_at((x, y)))
                    img1.set_at((n - 1 - y, x), img0.get_at((x, y)))
            for y in range(a - 1):
                for x in range(n):
                    img1.set_at((x, n - 1- y), img1.get_at((x, y)))
            scr = pygame.transform.scale(img1, (SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H))
        elif filterNum == 3:
            for y in range(self.h):
                for x in range(self.w):
                    r0, g0, b0, alpha = self.img.get_at((x, y))
                    c = (255 - r0, 255 - g0, 255 - b0)
                    scr.set_at((x,y), c)
                pygame.display.update()
        elif filterNum == 4:
            for y in range(self.h):
                for x in range(self.w):
                    r0, g0, b0, alpha = self.img.get_at((x, y))
                    gray = int(0.3 * r0 + 0.59 * g0 + 0.11 * b0)
                    c = (gray//128 * 128, gray//128 * 128, gray//128 * 128)
                    scr.set_at((x, y), c)
                pygame.display.update()
        elif filterNum == 5:
            n = 5
            grid = [[0] * n] * n
            for y in range(n // 2, self.h - n // 2):
                for x in range(n // 2, self.w - n // 2):
                    self.get_pixel_grid(x, y, n, grid)
                    x1 = random.randint(0, n - 1)
                    y1 = random.randint(0, n - 1)
                    scr.set_at((x, y), grid[y1][x1])
                pygame.display.update()
        elif filterNum == 6:
            n = 5
            grid = [[0] * n] * n
            for y in range(n // 2, self.h - n // 2):
                for x in range(n // 2, self.w - n // 2):
                    self.get_pixel_grid(x, y, n, grid)
                    x1 = random.randint(0, n - 1)
                    y1 = random.randint(0, n - 1)
                    scr.set_at((x, y), grid[y1][x1])
                pygame.display.update()
        elif filterNum == 6:
            n = 5
            grid = [[0] * n] * n
            for y in range(n // 2, self.h - n // 2):
                for x in range(n // 2, self.w - n // 2):
                    self.get_pixel_grid(x, y, n, grid)
                    x1 = random.randint(0, n - 1)
                    y1 = random.randint(0, n - 1)
                    c1 = random.randint(0, n - 1)
                    graw = (c1[0] + c1[1] + c1[2]) // 3// 32*32
                    c = (gray, gray, gray)
                    scr.set_at((x, y), c)
                pygame.display.update()
        self.img = scr.copy()
    def get_pixel_grid(self, x0, y0, sideLen, pixelGrid):
        n = sideLen // 2
        for y in range(-n, n + 1):
            for x in range(-n, n + 1):
                pixelGrid[y + n][x + n] = self.img.get_at((x + x0, y + y0))
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I would recommend to use modules  like PyQt and Tkinter, as they are intended to make applications and thus they do already a lot of the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is too long to read and there are no comments so I'm just gonna answer the main question:

To show or hide the text, just use a boolean variable, only blit the text if true.

If you want the text to be visible for a certain amount of time, change the value of this boolean variable depending on if a timer has ended. You could do this by counting frames or by using pygame.time. This is how you could do the latter:

```
import pygame.time


class Timer:

    # Time in ms:
    def __init__(self, duration):
        self.timer_start_time = 0
        self.duration = duration

    def start(self):
        self.timer_start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    def has_ended(self):
        return pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.timer_start_time >= self.duration


pygame.init()

# A timer for 5 seconds:
timer = Timer(5000)
timer.start()

while True:
    if timer.has_ended():
        print("The timer has ended")
        break
```